# Stripe API - Get all Skus for a Product

Tags: stripe-payments

Using the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) to build a simple e-comm site. I initially was requesting all SKUs but realized what I really wanted was to display all Products.

For example, instead of listing all the variations (SKUs) of Product A, Product B, and Product C, I want to list the main Product A, Product B, and Product C. When the user view the details of Product A, then they see all related SKUs (sizes, colors, etc).

The Stripe API has an endpoint for [retrieving all products](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/list), and an endpoint for [retrieving a single product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/retrieve), but I don't see a property on the [`product` object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object) with the associated SKUs for that product?

How do you retrieve all SKUs for a specific Product using the Stripe API?

Comment: You're right, there's not a property on the Product object that lists all SKUs. But what should be able to do is list SKUs, specifying a particular `product` https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus/list#list_skus-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the [SKUs API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus/list). One of the endpoints there will list the SKUs. You can filter these SKUs based on the `product`. i.e.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/skus?limit=3 \
    -u sk_test_9GavlLpfiKewqeCBXvRvmVgd: \
    -d product=PRODUCT_ID
    -G
```

Where `PRODUCT_ID` is a good typed product, not a service.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see this in the SKUs endpoint, does exactly what I need.